# How can I call multiple popups?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using W3School Popups but Im having a hard time activating multiple popups. When I activate second it always opens up first.

**CSS:**

```
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
 <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

**This is how I tried calling it twice:**

```
<!-- Popup 1 -->
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<!-- Popup 2 -->
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup two!
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopupTwo">A Simple Second Popup!</span>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var popuptwo = document.getElementById("myPopupTwo");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
<script>
```

And it didn't worked, so how can I call this popup to open on a different place and have different content. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified `myFunction` to take the id as an argument, this way you can specify which popup to toggle. Also fixed a slight syntax error `var popupTwo = .....; popup.classList` since popup was `undefined` and throwing an error.

```html
    <!-- Popup 1 -->
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction('myPopup')">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Popup 2 -->
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction('myPopupTwo')">Click me to toggle the popup two!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopupTwo">A Simple Second Popup!</span>
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction(id) {
      var popup = document.getElementById(id);
      popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much its working fine. So the error was because I was using same myFunction?

Comment: Your error was that myFunction always toggled the same popup, regardless of which text you actually clicked. We modified it so each onClick handler specifically tells the function which popup to show.